# Eccentric circles

Tags: calculus, circles, area

I have an equation to calculate the distance to the outside of a circle from an eccentric point within the circle.

$$x = E\cos(a) + 0.5\sqrt{(D^2) - 4*(E^2)\sin(a)^2}$$

Where:
$E$ = eccentricity,
$D$ = Circle diameter,
$a$ = angle (the maximum distance between the eccentric point and the circle perimeter is at 0 degrees)

If the centre point of the circle is labelled $A$, the eccentric point is labelled $B$ and the point on the perimeter of the the circle at any given angle is $C$, the equation gives the length of line $BC$ at a a given angle between line $BC$ and line $BA$.

I thought there would be a way to integrate this equation to get an area thats is bounded by lines at two different angles and the perimeter of the circle, but my calculus and trigonometry skills are not up to scratch.

[Reference image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmwqN.png)
[Reference image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DjMz.png)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "an area between two angles".

Comment: The area that is bounded by two lines at angle 1 and 2 and the perimeter of the circle, I'll try add a picture of it

Comment: Do you want to calculate the area of  "eccentric" sector?

Comment: What's meant by a "line at angle 1"? Where are these angles? What do they have to do with your "eccentric point"?

Comment: Yes the area of the eccentric sector, I've added an image to help explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symbols slightly altered.. $( \rho, R, \theta, \epsilon ) = ( - , D/2, \alpha, E)$ correspond.

Eccentric radius $\rho$, Circle radius $R$, Eccentric polar angle $\theta $

$$  \epsilon^2  + \rho^2 - 2 \epsilon  \rho  \cos \theta  = R^2  \tag{1}$$

Solve quadratic and taking positive sign to evaluate to right of eccentricity,

$$ \rho = \epsilon \cos \theta +  \sqrt{R^2 - ( \epsilon \sin \theta)^2 )    }  \tag{2} $$

Its square is needed in area polar formula

$$ 
\rho^2 = \epsilon ^2 \cos ( 2 \theta) + R^2 +( 2 \epsilon \cos \theta) \sqrt{R^2 - ( \epsilon \sin \theta)^2   }  \tag {3} $$

$$ 2\, dArea = \rho^2 d \theta \,   \tag{4}$$

Integrate within limits w.r.t. $\theta $ independent variable.

$$ 2 Area  = \int_{\theta_1} ^{\theta_2} \rho^2 d \theta \,   \tag{5} $$

Hope I made no error and hope you will take it to finish the integral  evaluation.

A closed form  solution got by Mathematica...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the area of the [sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector#Area) centered at $A$ to that of the [triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle) $CBA$.

Comment: Cant believe I didn't see that! I guess sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes, thanks!

Comment: I thought about it again and this method would only work if the sector intersects point A? I've added another reference image where the sector i want to find the area for does not intersect point A (area bounded by lines $BC1$, $BC2$ and the perimeter of the circleI)

Comment: What is given?  $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,E, D $ these four are inputs, right?

Comment: @L.Bouwmeester: in this case the difference of the areas is a crossed quadrilateral that you can decompose in two triangles.